# What defines "Looking an Enderman in the eye"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, when you look an Enderman "in the eye", it will aggro the mob. But what determines "Looking him in the eye"?

- Where does the cursor have to be?
- How far away can you be?
- Can I "look through" blocks like glass/water/leaves?

Comment: I know that you can look through blocks, and I've found that looking at the legs might aggrivate it sometimes. Not sure enough to post an answer though.

Comment: Second bullet point: [From how far will Endermen notice your gaze?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30423/from-how-far-will-endermen-notice-your-gaze)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anywhere from the knees and above will aggro the Enderman. They will aggro from as far as [64 blocks away](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Behavior). Except for water and lava, looking through any type of block will prevent the aggro, as well as wearing a pumpkin on your head. If you're trying to aggro an enderman, the easiest way is to look at the torso, as it's the widest area; also, you likely won't be looking too high, as is more possible when aiming for the head.

Looking at an enderman's feet will not aggro him. The best attack method, then, is to get close to them (or aggro them so they teleport to you) and then look at their feet and attack with melee. Standing under a two or 2.5 block high shelter will keep them from hitting you, since they are 3 blocks tall. They will not teleport away, and can be treated like a zombie at that point, continuously attacking as they advance until they die.

They cannot be hit by a ranged attack, including damage or poison potions, even if the cursor is not hitting the enderman when the shot is fired/potion is thrown. They always teleport away before taking damage.

Comment: They're also 3 blocks tall, so you can stand under a 2-block roof and not get hit by them.

Comment: +1 for sharing a technique of fighting him under a block just above the head of Steve.

Comment: I should clarify that you have to be about a block away from the enderman, otherwise they can reach you from where you are - further if you're in a 2.5 block high space.